# HTML notification on button press

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a buzzer app that when the user enters the site it alerts them to input there name into the alert box then when they press the button i want it to tell me there name i dont care about how to get this if its by a online database or via text or email as long it is only that button that needs to be presssed.

ive tryed using firebase but found it too confussing so if anyone can explain it in a way i can understand that could also solve this problem

```
<html>
<head>

  <title>Buzzer Page</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"></link>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

  <link rel="icon" href="Clever person.jpg" type="image/jpg">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

  <main>
    <div class="center">
      <button id="buzzingButton" onclick="buzz()"><img src="Clever person.jpg" width="100px"</img><br><h1>Press To Buzz</h1></button>
    </div>
  </main>


</body>
</html>
```

now my css

```
body {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.lowgif.com/full/c3a75154a9816ee0-wallpaper-gif-by-matthew-butler-find-share-on-giphy.gif');
  background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
  color: lightgreen;
}

.center {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#buzzingbutton {
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
  width: 700px;
  height:auto;
}

#buzzingbutton:hover {background-color: #3e8e41}

#buzzingButton:active {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);

}
```

now my javascript

```
var name = prompt("Please enter your name so we know who pressed the buzzer","<ENTER NAME HERE>")

var snd = new Audio("Buzzer-sound.mp3");

function buzz() {
  snd.play();
  snd.currentTime=0
  })
}
```

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--html-->
<input type="text" id="name">
 <button onclick = "buzz()">PressMe</button>

<!--Javascript-->
function buzz(){
    var name = document.getElementById("name");
    var displayName = name.value;
    alert(displayName);
}
```

That should do the trick, to display alerts just use the `alert();` function. You can also include text in it by simply doing `alert("Insert text here");`. Hope this works for you :)

Comment: I added the input html tag because I didn't know where you were getting the name of the user from. If you're getting it from somewhere else inputting a variable containing the name within the alert() function should still work.